# vlcj 4.2.0 MediaPlayer.media().play() or mediaListPlayer.controls().play() raise a fatal error in a linux docker container

Tags: libvlc, vlcj

My environment is an Alpine container on which I am installing vlc

```
FROM fabric8/java-alpine-openjdk8-jre
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add vlc vlc-xorg vlc-daemon
```

From this container, I am able to convert my file using vlc command line,. (some errors occur but the file is converted)

```sh
vlc -I dummy 1234.mp4 --no-sout-video  --sout "#transcode{acodec=mp3, ab=96, channels=2,samplerate=44100}:standard{mux=mp4,dst=1234.mp3,access=file}" vlc://quit
[000055f958d31180] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[000055f958d31180] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[00007f753b5bcb60] main libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
[000055f958d35640] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[00007f753b5bcb60] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[000055f958d35640] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[000055f958f54140] idummy demux: command `quit'
ls -ltrah 1234.mp3
-rw-r--r--    1 1001     root        4.9M Dec 11 23:27 1234.mp3
```

I am trying then to do the same with vlcj on the same container but mediaApi.play is raising a fatal error

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000003f36, pid=7, tid=0x00007fb727b71b20
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_222-b10) (build 1.8.0_222-b10)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.222-b10 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 3.13.0
# Distribution: Custom build (Wed Oct  2 14:20:25 UTC 2019)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000003f36
```

**[EDIT] async conversion (wait or sleep removal)**

**Case: MediaPlayer.media().play**

Both mediaApi.prepare and mediaApi.isValid return true.

```java
@Singleton
class ConverterMPService() {
    val VLC_GLOBAL_OPTIONS = arrayListOf<String>(
            "--file-logging",
            "--logfile=tim.log",
            "--log-verbose=3",
            ":no-sout-video",
            ":intf", "dummy"
    )
    private val LOG = Logger.getLogger(ConverterMPService::class.java)
    var factory = MediaPlayerFactory(VLC_GLOBAL_OPTIONS)
    var mediaPlayer = factory.mediaPlayers().newMediaPlayer()

    fun onStart(@Observes ev: StartupEvent?) {
        LOG.info("The vlc converterMP is starting...")
    }

    fun onStop(@Observes ev: ShutdownEvent?) {
        LOG.info("The vlc converterMP is stopping...")
        release()
    }

    fun convert(source: File, target: File) {
        if (target.exists()) target.delete()
        val options = arrayOf<String>(
                ":no-sout-video",
                ":sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=96,channels=2}:standard{mux=mp4,dst=${target.path},access=file}",
                ":intf", "dummy"
        )
        if (source.exists()) {
            val mediaApi = mediaPlayer.media()
            mediaPlayer.events().addMediaPlayerEventListener(LoggingMediaPlayerEventAdapter() as MediaPlayerEventListener)
            mediaPlayer.events().addMediaPlayerEventListener(object : MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
                override fun finished(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
                    LOG.info("Finished MepiaPlayer")
                    //blobStorageService.upload(target)
                }
            })
            var bPrepare = mediaApi.prepare(source.path, *options)
            LOG.info("Mediaplayer prepare ${source.name}:$bPrepare")
            var bIsvalid = mediaApi.isValid
            LOG.debug("Mediaplayer validation check of ${source.name} is $bIsvalid")
            var bPlay = mediaApi.play(source.path, *options)
            LOG.debug("Mediaplayer playing ${source.name} is $bPlay")
        }
    }

    fun release() {
        LOG.info("Releasing mediaPlayer")
        mediaPlayer.release()
        LOG.info("Releasing factory")
        factory.release()
    }
}
```

But JVM crash occurs

```sh
2019-12-13 23:02:18,262 INFO  [com.lg.vlc.ConverterMPService] (main) The vlc converterMP is starting...
2019-12-13 23:02:18,281 INFO  [com.lg.vlc.ConverterService] (main) The vlc converter is starting...
2019-12-13 23:02:18,281 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) speech-microsoft-service 1.0-SNAPSHOT (running on Quarkus 1.0.1.Final) started in 3.125s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
2019-12-13 23:02:18,286 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated.
2019-12-13 23:02:18,286 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, kotlin, resteasy, resteasy-jackson]
2019-12-13 23:02:34,081 INFO  [com.lg.spe.api.LoggingFilter] (vert.x-worker-thread-0) Request POST /speech2text/audio/addmp/1234mp from IP 172.17.0.1:46948
2019-12-13 23:02:36,051 TRACE [com.lg.vlc.LoggingMediaPlayerEventAdapter] (vert.x-worker-thread-0) mediaChanged(mediaPlayer=uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.base.MediaPlayer@fb6ecb,media=uk.co.caprica.vlcj.media.MediaRef@2f89dc8f)
2019-12-13 23:02:36,059 TRACE [com.lg.vlc.LoggingMediaPlayerEventAdapter] (vert.x-worker-thread-0) volumeChanged(mediaPlayer=uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.base.MediaPlayer@fb6ecb,volume=-1.0)
2019-12-13 23:02:36,066 INFO  [com.lg.vlc.ConverterMPService] (vert.x-worker-thread-0) Mediaplayer prepare 1234mp.mp4:true
2019-12-13 23:02:36,066 DEBUG [com.lg.vlc.ConverterMPService] (vert.x-worker-thread-0) Mediaplayer validation check of 1234mp.mp4 is true
2019-12-13 23:02:36,070 TRACE [com.lg.vlc.LoggingMediaPlayerEventAdapter] (vert.x-worker-thread-0) mediaChanged(mediaPlayer=uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.base.MediaPlayer@fb6ecb,media=uk.co.caprica.vlcj.media.MediaRef@6df18742)
2019-12-13 23:02:36,074 DEBUG [com.lg.vlc.ConverterMPService] (vert.x-worker-thread-0) Mediaplayer playing 1234mp.mp4 is true
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000003f36, pid=275, tid=0x00007f650d03db20
```

And the dist file size is 0

```sh
ls -ltrah 1234*
-rw-r--r--    1 1001     root       75.9M Dec 13 22:32 1234mp.mp4
-rw-r--r--    1 1001     root           0 Dec 13 22:32 1234mp.mp4.mp3
```

**Case mediaListPlayer.controls().play()**

```java
@Singleton
class ConverterService() {
    val LOG = Logger.getLogger(ConverterService::class.java)
    val VLC_GLOBAL_OPTIONS = arrayListOf<String>(
            "--file-logging",
            "--logfile=tim.log",
            "--log-verbose=3",
            ":no-sout-video",
            ":intf=dummy"
    )
    var mediaFactory = MediaPlayerFactory(VLC_GLOBAL_OPTIONS)
    var mediaListPlayer = mediaFactory.mediaPlayers().newMediaListPlayer()
    var mediaPlayer: EmbeddedMediaPlayer = mediaFactory.mediaPlayers().newEmbeddedMediaPlayer()

    fun onStart(@Observes ev: StartupEvent?) {
        LOG.info("The vlc converter is starting...")
mediaListPlayer.mediaPlayer().setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer)
    }

    fun onStop(@Observes ev: ShutdownEvent?) {
        LOG.info("The vlc converter is stopping...")
        release()
    }

    private fun release() {
        LOG.info("Releasing mediaListPlayer")
        mediaListPlayer.release()
        LOG.info("Releasing factory")
        mediaFactory.release()
    }

    fun convert(source: File, target: File) {
        if (target.exists()) target.delete()
        if (source.exists()) {
            val options = arrayOf<String>(
                    ":no-sout-video",
                    ":sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=96,channels=2}:standard{mux=mp4,dst=${target.path},access=file}",
                    ":intf=dummy"
            )
            var mediaList = mediaFactory.media().newMediaList()
            mediaList.media().add(source.path, *options)
            val mediaListRef = mediaList.newMediaListRef()
            try {
                mediaListPlayer.list().setMediaList(mediaListRef)
            } finally {
                mediaListRef.release()
            }
            mediaListPlayer.events().addMediaListPlayerEventListener(LoggingMediaListPlayerEventAdapter())
            mediaListPlayer.events().addMediaListPlayerEventListener(object : MediaListPlayerEventAdapter() {
                override fun mediaListPlayerFinished(mlp: MediaListPlayer?) {
                    if (null != mlp) {
                        for (mrl in mlp.list().media().mrls()) {
                            var f = File("$mrl.mp3")
                            LOG.info("Output ${f.path} size is ${f.length()}")
                            // blobStorageService.upload(target)
                        }
                    }
                    LOG.info("mediaListPlayerFinished")
                }
            })
            if (null != mediaListPlayer.mediaPlayer().mediaPlayer()) {
                mediaListPlayer.mediaPlayer().mediaPlayer().events().addMediaPlayerEventListener(LoggingMediaPlayerEventAdapter())
            } else LOG.info("mediaListPlayer.mediaPlayer().mediaPlayer() is null")
            mediaListPlayer.controls().play()
        }
    }
}
```

JVM crash occurs

```sh
2019-12-13 22:53:07,964 INFO  [com.lg.vlc.ConverterMPService] (main) The vlc converterMP is starting...
2019-12-13 22:53:07,984 INFO  [com.lg.vlc.ConverterService] (main) The vlc converter is starting...
2019-12-13 22:53:07,984 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) speech-microsoft-service 1.0-SNAPSHOT (running on Quarkus 1.0.1.Final) started in 2.504s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
2019-12-13 22:53:07,988 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated.
2019-12-13 22:53:07,989 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, kotlin, resteasy, resteasy-jackson]
2019-12-13 22:53:17,456 INFO  [com.lg.spe.api.LoggingFilter] (vert.x-worker-thread-0) Request POST /speech2text/audio/add/1234 from IP 172.17.0.1:46940
2019-12-13 22:53:19,397 INFO  [com.lg.vlc.ConverterService] (vert.x-worker-thread-0) mediaListPlayer.mediaPlayer().mediaPlayer() is null
2019-12-13 22:53:19,459 INFO  [com.lg.vlc.LoggingMediaListPlayerEventAdapter] (vert.x-worker-thread-0) MediaListPlayer nextItem
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000003f36, pid=136, tid=0x00007f0bd628fb20
```

**But** in that case the dist file is ok. The crash came after the conversion and before the finished trigger

```sh
ls -ltrah 1234*
-rw-r--r--    1 1001     root       75.9M Dec 13 22:53 1234.mp4
-rw-r--r--    1 1001     root        4.9M Dec 13 22:53 1234.mp4.mp3
```

I have tried different linux images, debian, ubuntu... I don't know it is related to a bad vlc installation.

Comment: FYI, I have raised this issue with the author: https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/issues/1060

Answer (score 0):

Your event listener looks very wrong to me:

```
override fun finished(p0: MediaPlayer?) {
                    p0!!.release()             // <------
                    isFinished = true
                }
```

You are trying to release the media player while it is processing events. Releasing the media player does a lot of clean-up, including freeing native resources. This is almost certainly the cause of your crash.

Instead, release the media player just before you release the factory.

Alternatively, you are looping on a non-threadsafe isFinished variable to check for the video being finished.

You set isFinished to true inside the event listener, your while loop (depending on timing) in another thread might then proceeed to factory.release() before the media player (and the associated native media player) have finished processing the event.

You may need a more sophisticated synchronisation mechanism.

You're basically trying to force synchronous processing with an asynchronous API.

There are classes in the vlcj "waiter" package that are designed to help with such problems.

Comment: Good catch, I have updated my code. However the JVM crash occurs before the triggering of 'finished' event. Actually I have just implemented [LoggingMediaPlayerEventAdapter.java](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/master/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/event/LoggingMediaPlayerEventAdapter.java) for debugging purpose. Please find [invocation logs](https://gist.github.com/timounet/2cf8b48ffe66381f2391d799589339ce). JVM crash seems to occur at/before 'opening triggering'. Is there a way to have more debug or logging tracks? I don't know it is related to a bad vlc installation. Many thanks

Comment: I am now using  mediaListPlayer.controls().play() (instead of MediaPlayer.media().play). the file is successfully converted but there is still a JVM crash before the release of mediaListPlayer. I have joined my [code / log and output](https://gist.github.com/timounet/f5c7a17f3204ba6a49ea0ea9d4487cb7/edit). I am close to complete my task but I can't find how to solve this.

Comment: Right, I am gonna review my program with an asynchronous way, but I am still believing mediaPlayer.media().payl() raises the JVM crash before the finished event trigger. Using mediaListPlayer.controls().play() seems to go further and I admit I need a more sophisticated synchronisation mechanism... I will let you know on my progress. Thank you for your help, I appreciate

Comment: May be useful if you update your original question with your latest code.

Comment: Done! I have avoided any synchronous processing, but I am still facing issues. I am wondering how it is possible add more debug?

Comment: On windows, there is no issue. I am wondering if there is limitation on linux? Does server-X is required for such operations?